# How to install fvm on mac, i 've try but get error?

Tags: flutter

I can't install fvm on mac, getting error like this, what is wrong, it's about brew or fvm?

[image: Error pict]

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Images should only be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Brew is telling you that it can't find a formula for FVM.

Try this:

`brew tap leoafarias/fvm`

`brew install fvm`

Instructions [here](https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/installation/).

Answer (score 0):

As in the official [documentation](https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/installation/) of fvm:

**1. Standalone (Recommended)**
You can download the standalone packages from the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/fluttertools/fvm/releases).

**2. Homebrew**
If you use the Homebrew package manager for Mac OS X, you can install FVM by running

**- Install**

```
brew tap leoafarias/fvm
brew install fvm
```

**- Uninstall**

```
brew uninstall fvm
brew untap leoafarias/fvm
```

**3. Pub package**

You are able to also install FVM as a pub package.

```
dart pub global activate fvm
```

However if you plan on using FVM to manage your global Flutter install we recommend installing as a standalone.

Answer (score 0):

The issues arose due to improper setup, I followed the following steps and FVM works properly in my system:

Step 1:  Open terminal and simply run below command or copy command from brew site, this will install brew in your machine.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Step2: After installing brew run the below commands or check that your terminal commands are available

```
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Step 3: Then Run below command

```
brew tap leoafarias/fvm
```

Step 4: Then run FVM install

```
brew install fvm
```

Step 5: Just run the below command to check successful installation of FVM in your system

```
fvm
```

Step 6 Now after this add Flutter SDK version through FVM, you can add multiple Flutter SDK version as per your project requirement.

For more detail you can read these articles

[FVM setup link 1](https://researchthinker.com/what-is-fvm-how-to-install-fvm-in-ubuntu-and-mac/)

[FVM setup link 2](https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/installation/)